# Bijective continuous function defined on "open" sets between $\Bbb R^n,~\Bbb R^m$ with discontinuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be open in $\Bbb R^n$, $f:U\to\Bbb R^m$ (where $n\neq m$). Suppose $f$ is injective and continuous, then must $f^{-1}$ be continuous?

The counterexample I know is when $U$ is **not** open, but I can't think of a counterexample for $U$ being open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a "$8$" shape in the plane, which we call $S$. We can construct $f:(0,1)\to S$ which is continuous and bijective, and which inverse is clearly not continuous. Chose $f(\frac12)$ to be the center point of the $8$, and then extend it so that the image of $f$ looks like this :

[image: eight shape]

If $f^{-1}$ was continuous, then $(0,1)$ would be compact, so this is a counter-example.